# How to Permanently Set MAC Address in a SMART TV using 'busybox ifconfig eth0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'?

Tags: mac-address

In my SMART TV, I want to set the MAC address permanently. however, after a restart, it reverts to the original MAC. Are there any methods to set it permanently using ADB?

I have used the command 'busybox ifconfig eth0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' to set the MAC address on my SMART TV but noticed that it reverts to the original MAC after a restart. Now, i am seeking guidance on writing ADB commands or other methods to ensure that the MAC address change persists permanently on my SMART TV.